# Do the Gauntlets of Flaming Fury infuse ranged weapon ammunition with magical properties?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, attack, ranged-attack

The description of the Gauntlets of Flaming Fury says:

> While you wear both of these steel gauntlets, any non-magical weapon you grasp with either gauntlet is treated as a magic weapon.

Does this property infuse both a ranged weapon and the ammunition being fired with this magical property, or just the ranged weapon and not the ammunition?

Answer (score 5):

#### The Gauntlets allow you to treat a ranged weapon as a magic weapon, but not the ammunition.

The Gauntlets of Flaming Fury state:

> While you wear both of these steel gauntlets, any non-magical weapon you grasp with either gauntlet is treated as a magic weapon.

This sentence imposes no restriction on the type of weapon, so it applies to any weapon, including range weapons.

Technically, the ammunition isn't magical, as [mundane ammunition is not classified as a weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/180449/62294), but the weapon they are fired from is. From the *Sage Advice Compendium*:

> **My fighter attacks a creature with a magical longbow and nonmagical arrows. Is the attack magical?**
> The attacks made by a magical ranged weapon are magical, even if the ammunition isn’t magical. (This point was clarified in the errata for the Dungeon Master’s Guide.)

So it probably doesn't even matter if the ammunition is magical or not, since the weapon, be it a bow or cross bow or other ammunition using ranged weapon, *is* magical, and so any attack made with it would count as magical.

#### The extra damage from the Gauntlets of Flaming Fury only work on melee weapons.

The Gauntlets of Flaming Fury state:

> As a bonus action, you can use the gauntlets to cause magical flames to envelop one or two **melee weapons** in your grasp. Each flaming weapon deals an extra 1d6 fire damage on a hit. The flames last until you sheath or let go of either weapon. Once used, this property can’t be used again until the next dawn.